# Десериализация списка List C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialize

Возникли проблемы при десериализации списка. Есть два PropertyGrid с классами Tube и Intersection с наследниками, в каждом из которых хранятся различные конфигурации разных классов. И всё это должно сохранятся в одном xml файле, известно только что значение PropertyGrid Tube должно быть выбрано один раз а вот значений PropertyGrid Intersection может быть несколько. Вот код который сохраняет все значения, проверка осуществляется через foreach:

```
public bool Save(Tube m_tube, Intersection m_intersection, string m_fileName)
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(m_fileName, settings))
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Part");

            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tube));
            ser.Serialize(writer, m_tube);

            foreach (IntersectionListItem de in MainViewModel.GetInstance().IntersectionView._IntersectionRepository._Intersections)
            {
                ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Intersection));
                ser.Serialize(writer, (Intersection)de._Intersection);
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Файл отлично создаётся. А вот как теперь осуществить десериализация через цикл? Вот файл который создался, были выбраны один из наследников класса Tube и три наследника класса Intersection

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Part>
  <Tube xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="OvalTube">
    <Type>OvalTube</Type>
    <WallThickness>25</WallThickness>
    <Height>25</Height>
    <Width>25</Width>
  </Tube>
  <Intersection xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="PlaneIntersection">
    <Type>PlaneIntersection</Type>
    <Position>Middle</Position>
    <Cut>InnerCut</Cut>
    <Movement>Robot</Movement>
    <Burning>Marking</Burning>
  </Intersection>
  <Intersection xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TubeIntersection">
    <Type>TubeIntersection</Type>
    <Position>Left</Position>
    <Cut>OuterCut</Cut>
    <Movement>RotationAxis</Movement>
    <Burning>Cutting</Burning>
    <_TubeDiameter>0</_TubeDiameter>
  </Intersection>
  <Intersection xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ConeIntersection">
    <Type>ConeIntersection</Type>
    <Position>Left</Position>
    <Cut>InnerCut</Cut>
    <Movement>Robot</Movement>
    <Burning>Cutting</Burning>
  </Intersection>
</Part>
```

Пробовала через цикл но не получается:

```
public bool Load(string m_fileName)
    {
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(m_fileName))
        {
            reader.ReadToFollowing("Tube");

            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tube));
            MainViewModel.GetInstance().PartView._Tube = (Tube)ser.Deserialize(reader);

            ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Intersection));
            MainViewModel.GetInstance().IntersectionView._Intersection = (Intersection)ser.Deserialize(reader);

            foreach (IntersectionListItem inter in MainViewModel.GetInstance().IntersectionView._IntersectionRepository._Intersections)
                MainViewModel.GetInstance().IntersectionView._IntersectionRepository.AddIntersection(inter);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Так читается только Tube и первый созданный Intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MainViewModel.GetInstance().IntersectionView._Intersection = (Intersection)ser.Deserialize(reader);

        foreach (IntersectionListItem inter in MainViewModel.GetInstance().IntersectionView._IntersectionRepository._Intersections)
            MainViewModel.GetInstance().IntersectionView._IntersectionRepository.AddIntersection(inter);
```

Сначала ты десериализируешь один Intersection и сохраняешь его в **IntersectionView._Intersection**, а потом пытаешься пройти циклом по списку **IntersectionView._IntersectionRepository._Intersections**. Очевидно, что этот список оказывается пустым, и в итоге ты получаешь единственный десериализированный Intersection.

Вообще с таким codestyle ошибки делаются легко и непринужденно, перепиши скорее.

Comment: А как? Может быть есть идеи? Уже несколько раз переписывала этот метод и никак не получается при десериализации сохранить в список.

Comment: while (serializer.CanDeserialize(reader))
{
    myIntersectionList.Add((Intersection)serializer.Deserialize(reader));
}